# drop first row in pysaprk sql

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark SQL script, which is supposed to drop first row after doing the SQL select to remove the header row.

```
    scSpark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "./mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar").getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(scSpark)

jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(hostname, jdbcPort, dbname)
connectionProperties = {
    "user": username,
    "password": password
}

sdfData = scSpark.read.csv(data_file, header=True, sep=",", encoding='UTF-8').cache()

sdfData.registerTempTable("books")
output = scSpark.sql('SELECT Categories AS type, `Course Material Title` AS title FROM books')
```

How could I drop the first row in the last line of my code to remove the header in the selected output?

I do not want the header go into the MySQL database data table, but I do need the header for the spark SQL in the last line, so I could not   set header=false in the read csv part

Comment: please show only relevant code. Remove unused parts. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show actual inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

While saving spark df, set header=False parameter.
It will automatically ignore the header

Comment: can not remove at saving df step,  as I have to 'SELECT Categories AS type, `Course Material Title` ... in the later spark sql step

Comment: can you share the command you are using to save df